# Test if a function given as a non-integrable ode set is Bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

Given that state space trajectories of an autonomous system do not cross,
can I deduce that a mapping function f:(x,y)→(x',y') given by a solution of an ODE of an autonomous system is bijective?

Other ideas on how to test if such a system is bijective will be appreciated.

note: the ODE set is non-linear and coupled so there is no explicit term for the ODE solution.

Comment: I do not understand what $g$ is here. How does it relate to $\dot{x} = f(x)$? Is it supposed to be the flow?

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)=\phi(\tau;x)$, the flow at a fixed time $\tau$? You have cases like $\dot x=f(x)=x^2$ where not all solutions will extend to the given time.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. $g$ is the solution of the ODE for some arbitrary integration time.

Comment: I will try to rephrase the question. Say I have a function $f:(x,y)\rightarrow(a,b)$ and this mapping is given by a solution of an ODE of an autonomous system. Is the mapping bijective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an ODE
$$\dot{x} = f(x), \quad x(0) = x_0$$
Denote families of solutions as $\{g(\cdot \ ;x_0)\}$, and you know that the trajectories do not cross on some set $[0,T]\times U$, with $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then the flow map 
$$\phi^t :U \mapsto \phi^t(U)$$
$$x_0 \mapsto g(t;x_0)$$
Will be bijective for all $t\in [0,T]$. This is what is meant by the trajectories do not cross. Otherwise $g(t;x_0) = g(t;y_0)$, so the only way for this to happen is if the initial data is the same $x_0 = y_0$.

Comment: thanks Dayton. I didnt understand your answer, what is $U$?

Comment: It is wherever your ODE is defined. If you have something like $f(x) = x/(1 - |x|^2)$, you will have to restrict initial data to $|x_0| < 1$ so in this case $U = B(0,1)$. However if $f$ is nicer like $f(x) = |x|^2$, then you can define solutions globally so $U = \mathbb{R}^n$. So your flow map may be bijective on a subset of $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So you are saying, yes a mapping given by an autonomous ODE is bijective in the domain where there is a solution to the ODE?

Comment: Yes because the flow has the property that $\phi^{t+s} = \phi^t\circ \phi^s$. So you are just changing your starting point to $\phi^s(x_0)$. In particular $\phi^{-t}(\phi^t(x_0)) = x_0$. But yes this only holds where a unique solutions exists.

Comment: Thanks for helping